# display first element in array with for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

How to display first element with for loop or for Each but here my code with forEach?

```js
var slides = ["slide 1", "slide 2", "slide 3", "slide 4", "slide 5"]
var str = ''

slides.forEach(function(slide) {
  str += '<li>'+ slide + '</li>';
}); 

document.getElementById("slideList").innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="slideList"></div>
```

Comment: You don't need a loop to display the _first_ element

Comment: What is wrong with your code and/or output it produces?